# Keycloak One Time Access

Tags: java, access-token, keycloak

I need a functionality to allow user to login into the system with limited functionality. 
 So my idea is, if the request comes from well-proven source, I generate the unique hashcode and send the email to the caller with login link with the hashcode. If the user clicks on the link, he will be redirected to the login controller, where I compare the hashcode, if valid then I create the user in Keycloak and log him into my system (dont know yet, how I can authenticate user in the Keycloak without accessing login form??). When the user logs out from the system, I delete the user in Keycloak.
 
This approach seems even to me as not completelly correct and it could even avoid the Keycloak, therefore I would like to ask, if there is some functionality in Keycloak for something like one time access or guest user? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

So my solution is to reuse the existing functionality in Keycloak with required action VERIFY_EMAIL. So I ask user who want to access my app for his email, then I create the user in Keycloak with random credentials and required action = VERIFY_EMAIL AND send him the credentials and link to log in. Once the user clicks on the link and put the correct credentials, he receives second email (Verify email action). There is a link on the address, which redirects the user back from where he came so in my case its the login to my secured app.